# Will 64-bit version of Java JDK work on 64-bit machine running 32-bit version of Ubuntu?

Tags: 64-bit, java, jdk

I have a 32-bit version of `Ubuntu 13.04` running on my `64-bit` machine.
I'm planning to install the 32-bit version of Eclipse 4.3 but I need to install Java JDK first.

I've had problems finding `32-bit` version of `Java JDK`, Oracle only lists 64 bit versions of java for linux.

In any case, does it matter what version of Java JDK I install? Will Java JDK `64-bit` work as well as it's counterpart (`Java JDK 32-bit`)?

I thought of installing the `64-bit` version of Ubuntu 13.04 but I don't want to go through the hustle after having spent more than 12 hours upgrading from Ubuntu `11.0`4 to `12.xx` ,and finally to `13.04`.

Comment: Does that mean that I can only install 32-bit software?

Comment: Added my comments as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 64-bit version of Ubuntu on a 64-bit compatible computer, then you can install all 64-bit software and 32-bit software. On a 32-bit system you can only install 32-bit software.

You need to install a 64-bit version of Ubuntu to be able to install 64-bit applications.

The reason for this is that the hardware needs to be able to handle 64-bit long instructions and the operating system needs to know this. A 32-bit system doesn't know this and can't therefor handle the extra 32-bit instructions on a 64-bit instruction. That's why you need to install a 64-bit operating system.

Also all 32-bit systems that are supported are with PAE kernels which means they can handle up to 64GB of RAM, and not the usual 4 GB maximum.

Have you got anymore questions feel free to comment. :)